# Unable to open jupyter notebook using pip on windows

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook

C:\Users\user>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in *run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\zmq_*init**.py", line 125, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init**.py", line 32, in 
raise original_error from None
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 36, in select_backend
raise ImportError(f"Importing {name} failed with {e}") from e
**ImportError: Importing zmq.backend.cython failed with builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 888 from C header, got 880 from PyObject**

Comment: I would look at using anaconda to set up environments. It is hard to know what is going on with your files but clearly something has an import error. Look at anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to rectify it by uninstalling the Jupyter notebook version that didn't work for me(5.0, 4.8) and installing a version that did work (4.0). I couldn't find this exact problem online but similar problems have occurred with NumPy module installations also fixed with a different version installation.

try:

```
pip uninstall notebook

pip install notebook==4.0
```